# How to access element using Watir and XPath

Tags: xpath, watir

I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<h1 id="header">Header</h1>
```

I would like to click it using Watir and XPath.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
browser.h1(:xpath, "//h1[@id='header']").click
```

Answer (score 11):

After watir-webdriver 0.5.1 selecting random element with an xpath was updated to:

```
browser.element(:xpath => "//h1[@id='header']").click
```

thanks to:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/watir-general/c6Orvy7Qalw

Answer (score 5):

```
browser.element_by_xpath("//h1[@id='header']").click
```

Sources:

- http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/XPath
- http://zeljkofilipin.com/2007/07/03/find-element-by-xpath/

Comment: this doesn't work for me. There does not appear to be element_by_xpath anymore

Comment: I think element_by_xpath was deprecated recently.

Comment: I have just checked,element_by_xpath was removed from watir-webdriver in version 0.5.1: https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/blob/master/CHANGES.md#051

Comment: Seems like it is replaced with `.element(:xpath => "str")`, have not tested it yet. Courtesy of https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/watir-general/c6Orvy7Qalw

Answer (score 1):

Also not XPath, but works:

```
browser.h1(:html, /header/).click
```

Comment: I assume `:html` means the html source of the element, correct? So in your example matching it with a pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Not using XPath, but it works:

```
browser.h1(:id, "header").click
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example using xpath here:

```
browser.element xpath: "//div/cite[contains(.,'some text')]/ancestor::div[@class='rc']/h3/a"
```

Checkout this simple framework that I uploaded to Github:
https://github.com/atfuentess/watir_cucumber_automation/

The stack used is: watir/cucumber/rspec

Perhaps it can help someone.