# Get the src value of an audio control using watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

I am writing automated tests for a web application using watir-webdriver and rspec.
I need to check an audio control has been loaded correctly. 
For images, I successfully checked the src attribute using this syntax:

```
$browser.image(:src => "/media/myimage.jpg").present?.should eql(true)
```

I was hoping to use a similar method to check the audio controls.
The web page structure looks like (HTML braces removed):

```
audio controls="controls" title=""
   source src="/media/R010201/R010201_audio_PhotoTime.ogg" type="audio/ogg "
audio
```

Note the *source* element is a child of the *audio* element. Using interactive Ruby (IRB), I am attempting to find the src tags using watir-webdriver.
I have tried the following:

```
$browser.audio.present?
```

- returns true.

```
$browser.audio.(:tag_name => 'source').text
```

-fails

```
$browser.element(:tag_name => 'source').src.text
```

-fails
What syntax should I use to get the value in the src attribute?

Comment: Which source you want to grab?

Comment: Edited question to remove irrelevant/unnecessary HTML element.

Comment: Removing html brackets actually makes it harder to read html IMHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper syntax would be:

```
browser.audio.source.src
#=> "/media/R010201/R010201_audio_PhotoTime.ogg"
```

If there is only one audio/source on the page, you could simply do:

```
browser.source.src
```

However, if there are multiple audio/source, you will need to find a more specific way of locating them. For example, if there is a unique parent div element around the audio element you would do:

```
browser.div(:id => 'unique_id').source.src
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do

```
$browser.source.attribute_value("src")
```

and obtain the `"file:///media/R010201/R010201_audio_PhotoTime.ogg"` value. It worked for me in the page I mocked up.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `tagname` which is `audio` in this case
I am not a `Watir` guy but I guess it's worth a shot.

```
browser.element(:xpath => "//*[@type='audio/ogg ']").attribute_value('src')
```

See the `api` doc [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Element#attribute_value-instance_method) and see another  SO thread related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23186253/3821981)